# Show links according to current time on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

Trying to create a site which will display 3 out of 4 hyperlinks until a certain time of day, e.g. `link1`, `link2`, `link3` visible from 04:00 – 23:00. After this time `link1`, `link2`, `link3` are hidden and only `link4` is visible (from 23:00 – 04:00).

I would like this all to happen on an `onload` event rather than `onclick` event. Could anyone possibly help?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour < 23 || hour > 4) {
    $("#link1").show()
    $("#link2").show()
    $("#link3").show()
    $("#link4").hide()
  }
  else {
    $("#link1").hide()
    $("#link2").hide()
    $("#link3").hide()
    $("#link4").show()
  }
  document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("link2").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("link3").innerHTML
  document.getElementById("link4").innerHTML
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <a id="link1" href="">Link1</a>
  <a id="link2" href="">Link2</a>
  <a id="link3" href="">Link3</a>
  <a id="link4" href="">Link4</a>
</body>
```

Comment: And what exactly is not working with this example?

Comment: It's working for me when I just call myFunction() from javascript.  wrap the function and call in document ready.  Fiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z7fkarjx/)

Comment: +for devlin. yes, inline event handlers such as `onload="myFunction()"` are _ick_; in addition, `onload` fires very late, after every last piece of the document has been loaded. What you want is the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, which is very easily used with jquery's `$(document).ready( ... )`

Comment: This is great guys thanks, really appreciate the help! @StephenP & Devlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this more simply by using appropriate DOM structure and CSS classes, with minimal javascript.

Similar to your structure, but putting the links in a container, I created:

```
<div id="link_area" class="timed_links">
    <a href="#" class="day">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="day">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="day">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="night">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="day night">Link 5</a>
</div>
```

This could use `<nav> ... </nav>` in place of a `<div>` if you're supporting HTML5.  You could use an ordered or unordered list for the links too.

I've identified the important block with an `id` of *link_area* and picked a class name *timed_links* to identify **what** is there — a set of time-based links.
Notice each link has a class *day* or *night* for when it's supposed to show. A link could have both classes day *and* night if it should always show.

Now style these, based on some rules — *day* links should not show at night, and *night* links should not show during the day.

```
.timed_links.day a.night,
.timed_links.night a.day
{
    display: none;
}
```

What this says is, "within a *timed_links* type of node that also has class *day*, select an `a` with class *night* and don't display it" ... and does the same for a *day* link when in a *night* container.

This will hide a link with both day+night classes like link 5, so we also have to insist that day+day links show and night+night links show — this must come *after* the above CSS rule:

```
.timed_links.day a.day,
.timed_links.night a.night
{
    display: initial;
}
```

Now all you have to do is set the correct class, *day* or *night* on the right element, the `class="timed_links"` block that contains the links.  Use your same javascript strategy to check the time, but just add a class to the container.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour < 23 || hour > 4) { // it's "day" time
    $('.timed_links').removeClass('night').addClass('day');
}
else { // it's "night" time
    $('.timed_links').removeClass('day').addClass('night');
}
```

Do this once, when the DOM is ready...

```
$('document').ready( function() {
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    // ... etc ...
} );
```

You could even do it regularly when the page is idle by setting a timer and changing the class on the *timed_links* container.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/82kLkmga/) I created from the pieces I wrote here.

Answer (score 0):

My call for this context. (pretty much self explanatory codes..)

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <a id="link1" data-min="4" data-max="23" href="">Link1</a>
  <a id="link2" data-min="4" data-max="23" href="">Link2</a>
  <a id="link3" data-min="4" data-max="23" href="">Link3</a>
  <a id="link4" data-min="23" data-max="4" href="">Link4</a>
</body>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").each(function(){
       var min  = $(this).data("min"), max = $(this).data("max");
       var hour = new Date().getHours();
       if(hour>=min && hour=<max) $(this).show();
       else $(this).hide();
   });
});
```